# What is the equivalent of the has_many 'conditions' option in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone tell me what is the equivalent way to do the following line in Rails 4?

```
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'", :order => :first_name
```

I tried the following:

```
has_many :friends, -> { where status: 'accepted' }, :through => :friendships , :order => :first_name
```

But I get the following error:

```
Invalid mix of scope block and deprecated finder options on ActiveRecord association: User.has_many :friends
```

Comment: Uh... could you post the whole file? I've never seen that error before.

Comment: Err, nevermind, I think I know what's wrong, will update...

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Needs to be the second arg:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, -> { where processed: true }
end
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many

**RESPONSE TO UPDATE:**

Put the order inside the block:

```
has_many :friends, -> { where(friendship: {status: 'accepted'}).order('first_name DESC') }, :through => :friendships
```

Comment: after replacing it in the second arg, i get this error : Invalid mix of scope block and deprecated finder options on ActiveRecord association: User.has_many :friends

Comment: Could you update your question with what you tried? Looks like you don't have enough room in your comment.

Comment: i used this -> { where status: 'requested' , :order => :created_at} and it works for me

Comment: thank you for help, please add my solution as second suggestion ^^

Comment: @medBo I'm not sure your solution is doing what you think it is. I think it ends up evaluating to `where(status: 'requested', order: :created_at)`, instead of actually applying an order to the relation. You could verify that by checking the generated SQL (`a_customer.friends.to_sql`)

Comment: i get error :(  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "users"."status" = 'accepted' AND "users"."order" = 'first_name' AND "friendships"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
PG::Error: ERROR:  column users.status does not exist
LINE 1: ...ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "users"."s...

Comment: it seem that scope is searching status attribute in the user model

Comment: You don't have a column in your `users` table called `status`. You can verify this by looking inside `db/schema.rb`. Are you trying to search against a method you defined called status? Or maybe you forgot to run a migration?

Comment: Err, we probably should move this discussion into a separate question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42261/discussion-between-medbo-and-kaleidoscope)

Answer (score 75):

While other answers on here are technically correct, they violate encapsulation. The *User* model should not know that the *Friendship* model has a column called `status`, and that it can have a specific value like `accepted`.

If you decide to make a change, to take advantage of Enums in Rails 4, for example, you would have to change both *User* and *Friendship* models. This could lead to bugs that maintaining encapsulation avoids.

I would expose a scope in the *Friendship* model:

```
scope :accepted, -> { where(status: :accepted) }
```

I would then use this scope in the *User* model, hiding any implementation details from *User*.

```
has_many :friendships, -> { Friendship.accepted }
has_many :friends, through: :friendships

# Or...

has_many :friends, -> { Friendship.accepted }, through: :friendships
```

You can go further and rename the scope to `accepted_friendships` to be clearer.

```
has_many :accepted_friendships, -> { Friendship.accepted }
has_many :friends, through: :accepted_friendships
```

Now you have successfully encapsulated implementation details in their respective models. Should anything change you only have one place to change it, reducing maintenance and increasing robustness.

Comment: your solution look cleaner, I will try it later on. +1

Comment: I am using the same type of code, but getting `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>` with this line: `has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, class_name: "User", -> { Friendship.accepted }`

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.2.5, it did not accept the syntax until i put the where before the rest of the arguments

Comment: @Riptyde4 sorry, I didn't read your earlier comment properly: The proc (`->{ Friendship.accepted }`) has to be the second argument, as my answer shows. So yes, it will be a syntax error if you don't have it in that order. My answer shows it in the correct order: `has_many :friends, -> { Friendship.accepted }, through: :friendships`

Comment: @Mohamad Sorry for the confusion, I didn't realize order mattered when I was trying it for myself. Your answer was very helpful to me

Comment: @Riptyde4 no worries. I'm glad you found it helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

A Rails 3.2 version of Mohamad's answer would be the following:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships, :order => :first_name

  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships,
           :conditions => proc { Friendship.accepted.where_ast }

  has_many :pending_friends, :through => :friendships,
           class_name => Friend,
           :conditions => proc { Friendship.pending.where_ast }
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :status, ->(status) { where(:status => status) }
  scope :accepted, -> { status('accepted') }
  scope :pending, -> { where(arel_table[:status].not_eq('accepted')) } 
end
```

**NOTES:**

- `where_ast` is important as it returns the AREL nodes that are required for the condition to work
- within the proc passed to `:conditions`, `self` is not always a model instance (e.g. when the association is merged with another query)
- Using raw SQL within your scopes and associations will likely cause issues at some point to do with namespacing of table names... use AREL.

Answer (score 3):

In order to work on **Rails 4.1** (my case), i had to put:

```
has_many :friends, -> { where(friendships: { status: 'accepted' }) }, through: :friendships
```

Note the S on friendships. It refers directly to the database name.

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :friends, -> { where(status: 'accepted').order('first_name')}, through: :friendships
```

or

```
has_many :friends, -> { where(status: 'accepted').order(:first_name)}, through: :friendships
```