# ActiveRecord, Rails 4: has_many :through with scoped conditions failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm working on a system where a `User` can be associated with another entity, a `Wedding`, in multiple ways through an `Attendance` model using `user_id`, `wedding_id` and `role` information. With help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307874/what-is-the-equivalent-of-conditions-in-has-many-rails-4) question, I sort of found my way of replacing `:conditions` with a Rails 4-style association. My associations are now these:

`User`:

```
has_many  :wedding_attendances
has_many  :weddings,
          through: :wedding_attendances
has_many  :marriages,
          -> { WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:spouse) },
          through: :wedding_attendances,
          class_name: 'Wedding'
has_many  :invitations,
          -> { WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:invitee) },
          through: :wedding_attendances,
          class_name: 'Wedding'
has_many  :ceremonies,
          -> { WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:worker) },
          through: :wedding_attendances,
          class_name: 'Wedding'
```

`Wedding`:

```
has_many  :wedding_attendances
has_many  :attendees,
          through: :wedding_attendances,
          class_name: 'User'
has_many  :spouses,
          -> { WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:spouse) },
          through: :wedding_attendances,
          class_name: 'User'
has_many  :invitees,
          -> { WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:invitee) },
          class_name: 'User',
          through: :wedding_attendances
has_many  :workers,
          -> { WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:worker) },
          class_name: 'User',
          through: :wedding_attendances
```

`WeddingAttendance`:

```
belongs_to :wedding
belongs_to :user

class << self
  def roles
    {
      spouse: 0,
      invitee: 1,
      worker: 2
    }
  end

  def find_by_role role
    if role.class == Symbol
      where(role: roles[role])
    else
      where(role: role)
    end
  end
end
```

Not as straightforward as I wanted, but apparently correct. Or not, because `User.first.weddings`, for example, raises the following error, even though `WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:spouse)` returns a correct result set:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:100:in `_reflect_on_association'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:537:in `source_reflection'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:697:in `check_validity!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:25:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:9:in `initialize'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:155:in `new'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:155:in `association'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:110:in `marriages'
        from (irb):51
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I like your question I will be looking at it in more details later on the day. Thanks for asking

Comment: Is it definitely `User.first.weddings` that returns the error rather than `User.first.marriages`? Your stacktrace seems to refer to `marriages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include a `source:` configuration option on your `has_many through:` associations. (You've correctly used `class_name` to identify the class at the other end but you need a little more than that).

From the [rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference):

> The :source option specifies the source association name for a has_many :through association. You only need to use this option if the name of the source association cannot be automatically inferred from the association name.

Because your associations are called `marriages`, `invitations` and `ceremonies` the `has_many through:` is looking for associations on `WeddingAttendance` called `marriage`, `invitation` and `ceremony` to follow to get the `Wedding` instance at the other end of the association.

If you add a `source: :wedding` to your `through` associations on `User` and a `source: :user` to your `through` associations on `Wedding` active record will be able to identify the associations it should follow.

Comment: That's it. Worked like a charm with `source:` :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Shadwell mentioned, you need to use `source` with `has_many :through`.

However I would just create my own method:

```
class User

  has_many  :wedding_attendances
  has_many  :weddings,
          through: :wedding_attendances

  def self.marriages
    self.weddings.where('wedding_attendances.role = ?', WeddingAttendance.find_by_role(:spouse))
  end
end
```

This is just a preference but I find it is easier to read.