# Rails use scopes on includes(:children)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**models**

```
class User
  has_many :pictures

class Picture 
  belongs_to User
  mount_uploader :picture, UserPictureUploader
  def self.profile
    find_by(is_profile: true)
  end
```

**controller**

```
User.includes(:pictures).where(...
```

**view**

```
=user.pictures.profile.picture_url
```

This is causing the following Problem, that each picture will be queried (again).
if we use `user.pictures.where(profile: true).picture_url` it won't make any new sql-queries.

#### question:

How can we use scopes on the already included result?

Answer (score 0):

Something like below will do

```
class User
  has_many :pictures
  scope :some_name, -> { includes(:pictures).where(your_query_here) }
end
```

Also, `scopes` are used only on a `Class`(in other words they are `class methods`), if you want to use it on the `instance`, then you need define an instance method something like below

```
class User
  has_many :pictures

  def some_name
    self.includes(:pictures).where(your_query_here)
  end
end
```

Comment: the problem is, that this query isnt working in rails:     includes(:pictures).where("user_pictures.is_profile = true")

Comment: @huanson You need to append `.references(:user_pictures)` at the end.

Comment: `User.includes(:pictures).where("user_pictures.is_profile = true").references(:user_pictures)` then just returns users who have a picture with that flag. but we want to include only those. i guess thats not possible in rails.

Comment: @huanson What do you mean by but we want to include only those?

Comment: we want all users, and including the pictures include(:pictures) where the profile picture (profile: true), so just include 1 picutre, if its there

Answer (score 0):

With a little digging I found this question

[What is the equivalent of the has_many 'conditions' option in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307874/what-is-the-equivalent-of-conditions-in-has-many-rails-4)

It looks like you can put conditions on your has_many relation to essentially be the scoped config you're looking for. It'd be something like:

```
has_many :old_pictures, :class_name => 'Picture', 
         :foreign_key => 'picture_id', -> { where('created_at < ?', Time.now - 7.days) }
```

Comment: Well it does, if you set this up then use includes(:old_pictures), it should eager-load the scoped version of pictures and not have to re-load them when they're used. (Of course, the query you're making will be different, this is an example)