# ActiveRecord: has_many choices limited to has_many of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to achieve something as follows where `PersonSubject` has many topics, but the choices of these topics are limited to the the selection of `topics` through another model (ie: through the associated `subject`):

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subject
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :topics
end

class PersonSubject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :topics  # where the choices are limited to the subject.skills
end
```

I would then like if any `person_subject.subject.topics` are deleted (or association removed), it would automatically update the `person_subject.topics` to no longer "point" to the `Topic`(s) that were deleted.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda to put arbitrary filters on an association. See [What is the equivalent of the has_many 'conditions' option in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307874/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-has-many-conditions-option-in-rails-4)

```
has_many :topics, -> { where(skill: subject.skills) }
```

I don't know that this is exact code will work without seeing your schema (what is the data type of `subject.skills`, and how do you join this with topic?). But hopefully this gets you on the right track

*edit*

in response to your comment, I think

```
has_many :topics, through: :skills
```

would work

Comment: Hey Max, I appreciate the help. Unfortunately I had made a typo the first time round, and had meant to write `topics` instead of `skills`. I figured I could do something like what you are saying, ie: limiting the `topics` of a `PersonSubject` record to those linked to by the associated `subject`, but I would also then like to know that removing any of the `subject.topics` for the `PersonSubject` record will actually update which `topics` 
are linked to from the `PersonSubject` record.

Comment: The problem with `through` is that it gives me all `topics` of the associated `subject`, whereas I would like to be able to set the `topics` of the `TutorSubject` record to be a subset of that of the `subject.topics` (or am I being silly? is there another way?)

Comment: @Arnoux I think you can combine the `has_many :through` with the lambda option in this case. How do you link Topic with PersonSubject? Each topic has a person_subject_id?

Comment: I was actually hoping to not have to have link the `Topic` back to `PersonSubject` at all. Perhaps what I am asking is not possible.

Comment: Can you share all relevant parts of your schema?